# wxpython how to display button label into xlwt

Tags: wxpython, xlwt

I want to print buttons label into excel when I press the button,the excel file created but I cant sent any information in it!Can somone help me,or I'm doing it all wrong?

```
import wx
from xlwt import *

w = Workbook()
ws1 = w.add_sheet('sheet 1')

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Button to Excel', size = (300,300))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        extBtn = wx.Button(panel, label="Exit",pos=(100,150))
        extBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose)

        btn = wx.Button(panel,label = "Mem 1",pos=(100,100))
        btn.Bind =(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.onButton)

    def onClose(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def onButton(self,event):
        print self.GetLabel() in ws1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=MyFrame(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
    w.save('a.xls')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues. First off, you bind the second button incorrectly. It should be bound the same way the first one. So change your binding code to the following:

```
btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
```

Note that there is no equals sign any more.

Next in the **onButton** method, you need to write data to the Excel file. Python's "in" operator does not do that. It is used to test if an item is in a collection or not. See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in) for more information.

Instead, you will want to use xlwt's **write** method to write the label to a cell. Here is a complete example:

```
import wx
from xlwt import *

w = Workbook()
ws1 = w.add_sheet('sheet 1')

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Button to Excel', size = (300,300))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        extBtn = wx.Button(panel, label="Exit",pos=(100,150))
        extBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose)

        btn = wx.Button(panel,label = "Mem 1",pos=(100,100))
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

    def onClose(self, event):
        w.save('a.xls')
        self.Close()

    def onButton(self,event):
        btn = event.GetEventObject()
        lbl = btn.GetLabel()
        ws1.write(0, 0, lbl)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=MyFrame(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note that I have also moved the save to the onClose function as I think that's a better place for it.

Comment: Thank you very much, can I ask something else?In the same code if I put a txtctrl and instead geting the label from the button (Mem1) write another name and when I press the button see the name into the excel?

Comment: Are you saying you want to get the value from the TextCtrl and write it to your Excel file? If you did that, you would just do something like value = self.myTxtCtrl.GetValue() and then write it out as before to whichever cell you want to